# How to replace between certain text

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok i have some text like below:

& leftsidetext sometext rightsidetext & %leftsidetext sometext rightsidetext%

Now i want to replace replacetext inside sometext just in: 
& leftsidetext sometext rightsidetext &

Comment: Can you give an another example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  "& leftsidetext sometext rightsidetext &", 
  "%leftsidetext sometext rightsidetext%"
]

let res = arr.map(str => str.indexOf("&") === 0 ? str.replace("sometext", "replText") : str)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -2):

It is really hard for me to understand your 'question', but I will start from the assumption that **'leftsidetext'** and **'rightsidetext'** are words that don't have spaces or characters other than letters from **'a'** to **'z'** upper or lowercase.

From there a solution could be:

```js
let theString='& leftsidetext sometext rightsidetext & %leftsidetext sometext rightsidetext%',
  theRegex=/& ([a-zA-Z]+) (.+) ([a-zA-Z]+) & %/,
  newvalue='Your new text'
  
console.log(theString.replace(theRegex,'& $1 '+newvalue+' $3 & %'))
```